# How to show circle on last entry of line chart with MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart library and showing a line chart. There is methods to show circles on all values but I want to show circle `ONLY` on `Last value`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set **setScatterShape** to CIRCLE

```
ScatterDataSet set2 = new ScatterDataSet(values2, "DS 2");
set2.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
```

Comment: You can't set ScatterDataSet data to linechart

Comment: I used combined chart but the ScatterDataSet shows at 0 and not on the linechart

Answer (score -1):

I have similar needs, draw the circle if and only if the selected position is highlighted.

**MyLineChart.java**

```
public class MyLineChart extends LineChart {


    public MyLineChart(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyLineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyLineChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();

        mRenderer = new MyLineChartRenderer(this, mAnimator, mViewPortHandler);
    }


    public void setHighIndex(int index) {
        ((MyLineChartRenderer) mRenderer).setHighIndex(index);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

**MyLineChartRenderer.java**

```
public class MyLineChartRenderer extends LineChartRenderer {


    public MyLineChartRenderer(LineDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    private float[] mCirclesBuffer = new float[2];
    /**
     * cache for the circle bitmaps of all datasets
     */
    private HashMap<IDataSet, DataSetImageCache> mImageCaches = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void drawCircles(Canvas c) {
        mRenderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        mCirclesBuffer[0] = 0;
        mCirclesBuffer[1] = 0;

        List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = mChart.getLineData().getDataSets();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSets.size(); i++) {

            ILineDataSet dataSet = dataSets.get(i);

            if (!dataSet.isVisible() || (!dataSet.isDrawCirclesEnabled() && -1 == highIndex) ||
                    dataSet.getEntryCount() == 0)
                continue;

            mCirclePaintInner.setColor(dataSet.getCircleHoleColor());

            Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

            mXBounds.set(mChart, dataSet);

            float circleRadius = dataSet.getCircleRadius();
            float circleHoleRadius = dataSet.getCircleHoleRadius();
            boolean drawCircleHole = dataSet.isDrawCircleHoleEnabled() &&
                    circleHoleRadius < circleRadius &&
                    circleHoleRadius > 0.f;
            boolean drawTransparentCircleHole = drawCircleHole &&
                    dataSet.getCircleHoleColor() == ColorTemplate.COLOR_NONE;

            DataSetImageCache imageCache;

            if (mImageCaches.containsKey(dataSet)) {
                imageCache = mImageCaches.get(dataSet);
            } else {
                imageCache = new DataSetImageCache();
                mImageCaches.put(dataSet, imageCache);
            }

            boolean changeRequired = imageCache.init(dataSet);

            // only fill the cache with new bitmaps if a change is required
            if (changeRequired) {
                imageCache.fill(dataSet, drawCircleHole, drawTransparentCircleHole);
            }

            int boundsRangeCount = mXBounds.range + mXBounds.min;

            //draw circle on line
            for (int j = mXBounds.min; j <= boundsRangeCount; j++) {

                Entry e = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j);

                if (e == null) break;

                //Draw the circle if and only if the selected position is highlighted
                if (j != highIndex)
                    continue;

                mCirclesBuffer[0] = e.getX();
                mCirclesBuffer[1] = e.getY() * phaseY;

                trans.pointValuesToPixel(mCirclesBuffer);

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(mCirclesBuffer[0]))
                    break;

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(mCirclesBuffer[0]) ||
                        !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(mCirclesBuffer[1]))
                    continue;

                Bitmap circleBitmap = imageCache.getBitmap(j);

                if (circleBitmap != null) {
                    c.drawBitmap(circleBitmap, mCirclesBuffer[0] - circleRadius, mCirclesBuffer[1] - circleRadius, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int highIndex = -1;

    public void setHighIndex(int index) {
        highIndex = index;
    }

    private class DataSetImageCache {

        private Path mCirclePathBuffer = new Path();

        private Bitmap[] circleBitmaps;

        /**
         * Sets up the cache, returns true if a change of cache was required.
         *
         * @param set
         * @return
         */
        protected boolean init(ILineDataSet set) {

            int size = set.getCircleColorCount();
            boolean changeRequired = false;

            if (circleBitmaps == null) {
                circleBitmaps = new Bitmap[size];
                changeRequired = true;
            } else if (circleBitmaps.length != size) {
                circleBitmaps = new Bitmap[size];
                changeRequired = true;
            }

            return changeRequired;
        }

        /**
         * Fills the cache with bitmaps for the given dataset.
         *
         * @param set
         * @param drawCircleHole
         * @param drawTransparentCircleHole
         */
        protected void fill(ILineDataSet set, boolean drawCircleHole, boolean drawTransparentCircleHole) {

            int colorCount = set.getCircleColorCount();
            float circleRadius = set.getCircleRadius();
            float circleHoleRadius = set.getCircleHoleRadius();

            for (int i = 0; i < colorCount; i++) {

                Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
                Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (circleRadius * 2.1), (int) (circleRadius * 2.1), conf);

                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
                circleBitmaps[i] = circleBitmap;
                mRenderPaint.setColor(set.getCircleColor(i));

                if (drawTransparentCircleHole) {
                    // Begin path for circle with hole
                    mCirclePathBuffer.reset();

                    mCirclePathBuffer.addCircle(
                            circleRadius,
                            circleRadius,
                            circleRadius,
                            Path.Direction.CW);

                    // Cut hole in path
                    mCirclePathBuffer.addCircle(
                            circleRadius,
                            circleRadius,
                            circleHoleRadius,
                            Path.Direction.CCW);

                    // Fill in-between
                    canvas.drawPath(mCirclePathBuffer, mRenderPaint);
                } else {

                    canvas.drawCircle(
                            circleRadius,
                            circleRadius,
                            circleRadius,
                            mRenderPaint);

                    if (drawCircleHole) {
                        canvas.drawCircle(
                                circleRadius,
                                circleRadius,
                                circleHoleRadius,
                                mCirclePaintInner);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the cached Bitmap at the given index.
         *
         * @param index
         * @return
         */
        protected Bitmap getBitmap(int index) {
            return circleBitmaps[index % circleBitmaps.length];
        }
    }
}
```